# How to get the modified time of a file being uploaded in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, file, time

Is there ever a way possible to get the actual creation / modification time of the file being uploaded, using JavaScript?

As for PHP, using `filectime()` and `filemtime()`, it only shows the date / time the file is uploaded, and not the time the file is actually created / modified on the source.

In short, what I want is to check the m-time of a file before/during/after upload (where-ever possible) and decide whether or not to store the file on the server, and report the same back to the client.

Answer (score 15):

If you're talking about the file date/time *on the user's machine*, you can get that via the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI) ([support](http://caniuse.com/#search=fileapi)), which provides [`lastModified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/lastModified), which is the date/time as a number of milliseconds since The Epoch (if you want a `Date`, you can pass that into `new Date`). (There's also the deprecated [`lastModifiedDate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#file-attrs), but that is deprecated and not supported on Safari [at least].) The File API is universally supported in modern browsers (the particular feature you'd be using is the [`File` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)). You'd get the value from the `File` object and include that information in a separate (for instance, hidden) field.

Here's a rough-but-complete example of reading the last modified date ([live copy](https://output.jsbin.com/kibidijewu/1)):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Show File Modified</title>
<style type='text/css'>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function showFileModified() {
        var input, file;

        // Testing for 'function' is more specific and correct, but doesn't work with Safari 6.x
        if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function' &&
            typeof window.FileReader !== 'object') {
            write("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
            return;
        }

        input = document.getElementById('filename');
        if (!input) {
            write("Um, couldn't find the filename element.");
        }
        else if (!input.files) {
            write("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
        }
        else if (!input.files[0]) {
            write("Please select a file before clicking 'Show Modified'");
        }
        else {
            file = input.files[0];
            write("The last modified date of file '" + file.name + "' is " + new Date(file.lastModified));
        }

        function write(msg) {
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.innerHTML = msg;
            document.body.appendChild(p);
        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action='#' onsubmit="return false;">
<input type='file' id='filename'>
<input type='button' id='btnShowModified' value='Show Modified' onclick='showFileModified();'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The reason you couldn't get the time from the uploaded file on the server is that only the content of the file is transmitted in the request, not the client's filesystem metadata.

Comment: Thanks Crowder, your sample works in Chrome. That really looked easy. Users of my clients will use IE only, that to IE6 or may be IE7, not beyond that. So tested my own codes in only IE. And BTW, do you know any any mobile phone browser supports this API. That is even more important than IE (or PC, to say). Any-ways, thanks again.

Comment: Thanks! In Safari the field seems to be called `lastModified` instead of `lastModifiedDate`.

Comment: @andrewdotn - Thank you for raising that. In the time since this answer as first posted, `lastModifiedDate` was deprecated and replaced with `lastModified`, and Safari never supported `lastModifiedDate`. I've updated the answer to use the more standard (now) one. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Fantastic, thanks! I’m happy to see that the updated demo works in Safari.

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript does not have access to the local filesystem, so you can't get to this information without using Flash, Java or Active-x.

Comment: *"JavaScript does not have access to the local filesystem"* It does on some browsers, like Chrome, Opera, Firefox...

Comment: Thanks Diodeus, Flash seems to be a good options. I will see if it fits into my logic. I have to actually upload multiple files from same page along with m-time.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps you could use javascript to get the *last modified* time, then use that in some other javacript to sort on that. This time will be in GMT.

```
var xmlhttp = createXMLHTTPObject();
xmlhttp.open("HEAD", "http://myurl/interesting_image.jpg" ,true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
    alert("Last modified: "+
     var lastModTimeForInterestingImage = xmlhttp.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"))
  }
}
xmlhttp.send(null);
```