# Preserve timestamp on php upload

Tags: php, javascript, apache, upload

I tried google as well as stackoverflow search, but either is my query stupid, or I am missing an important point.

**Question**:
Is there a way to preserve `timestamp(ctime, mtime)` on files uploaded via `Apache/php` ?

All my files timestamps will get reset to the moment of upload... :(

I sought ways to determine the timestamp on the local system, but that does not seem to be possible with php/js (Java or ftp+php shouldwork, but are not applicable for my case).

thanks,
Alexander

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7612943/632390

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a function called `stat` which could possibly be used at the point of uploading the file.

Example:

```
$file = $_FILES['new_file'];
$stat = stat($file);
$mod_time = $stat['mtime'];
```

You can then use `touch` to change the modification time of the newly created file
http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php

```
$new_file = touch($filename, $mod_time);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello Kari, thanks for suggestion, I tried that already and the temp file has already current timestamp, so no benefit from stat()... :(