# Getting original file meta-data from FineUploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I am aware that performing a `stat` on an uploaded file will only give creation/modified/access dates at the time the file was uploaded.

So a very quick question, is there any way for FineUploader to access the original file meta-data for these fields and send it along with the upload request?

From what I understand, this is probably not possible, but it never hurts to ask!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not natively supported by Fine Uploader. You could open up an [issue](https://github.com/widen/fine-uploader/issues/new) if you think it would be a useful feature.

---

That being said, you **can** do it using Fine Uploader's callbacks and the FileAPI. The best you could do in any browser right now is get the [`lastModifiedDate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#file-attrs) using the [FileAPI](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI) and add that to the parameters for each file in your [`onSubmitted` callback](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submitted),

```js
var getLastModifiedDate = function(file) { 
/* Cross-broswer File API shim to get Last Modified Date of a file */
}

var fineuploader = new qq.FineUploader/* ... */

    /* snippet */
    callbacks: {

        onSubmitted: function(id, name) {
            var file = fineuploader.getFile(id),
                lastModified = getLastModifiedDate(file);
            fineuploader.setParams({ lastModified: lastModified }, id);
        });
    }
    /* snippet */
```

I found [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612894/how-to-get-the-modified-time-of-a-file-being-uploaded-in-javascript-php) which has an example and a shim to retrieve the `lastModifiedDate`.

Comment: At the moment my callback (if getinProgress() == 0) creates dynamic hidden fields for uuid, name, size, and upload status - do you think I will be able to getLastModified and append this at the same time?

Comment: Yes. Note that you will be constrained by the list of browsers that have the [`File` API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi).

Comment: Having some trouble getting the properties. I'm instantiating fine uploader using a div: `<div id="jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader"></div>`. If I try to access the files information using `input = document.getElementById('jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader');`, it throws the error saying 'files isn't supported in this browser', although I'm using the latest firefox. I'm guessing trying to get the 'files' data from the FineUploader instance like this isn't the way to do it?

Comment: Just looking further, I see that the div in my previous comment spawns an input of type file and name="file", but no id. I'm guessing (hoping) there's a way to set an option to instantiate the uploader with a parameter that will allow me to specify the id attribute of the file input, so that I can reference it using getElementByID? I can't find anything in the docs.

Comment: You could use [`getFile`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html) to get the file object based on a file id.

Comment: `fineuploader.getFile(id)` now returns `lastModifiedDate` property

Comment: Worth noting that File.lastModifiedDate [is now deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), but it should be fine to simply use File.lastModified instead.