# How can I upload a file to a browser without its modified time?

Tags: javascript, file

I saw these ways to access the modified date here: [How to get the modified time of a file being uploaded in JavaScript/PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612894/how-to-get-the-modified-time-of-a-file-being-uploaded-in-javascript-php).

How can I prevent any of these ideas to work? Or at least to know whether a specific site uses a way to gather this information?

This is duplicate but the oriinal question has no answer.

Comment: Practically speaking, as a user, if you're nervous about the site knowing the modified date, simply change the modified date (perhaps on a copy of the file) and upload *that*…

Comment: I didn't see that copying a file changes the modified date. But what about the created date - is it possible to see also this?